# Reusable component: toolbar like in astro app for Android

Tags: android

I really like the toolbar in Astro app for Android and I was wondering: Do you know if it is reusable component, is it open source, if yes - where to find it; if not - can you provide a link to similar open source component.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make yourself a custom view, e.g. `class myToolbar extends LinearLayout(context) {}` that contains your toolbar buttons and add this to any other Views where you want to display the toolbar.

Comment: well, I did that, enclosed it in Horizontal Scroll but I still miss arrows at both sides (which get grayed if no scroll is possible).
Since it seems quite a common component I thought that there is no need to reinvent the wheel...